# How to handle network down when calling a API

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, distributed-transactions

Today, I am thinking a simplified scenario as follows:

I have my own payment system and when user come to save money, I use a form to save transaction data in my own DB. Before saving my own record, I need call Bank payment system which has a Webservice API like

`public boolean pay(userInfo userInfo, float money)`.

Based on the result returned, I determine whether save my own data or not.

My question is if after calling the Bank payment API, my own network is off, and no result back. How to determine whether I need to save my own Form record or not. Maybe bank payment system has already processed this transaction? How to make two part data synchronized?

We cannot change bank payment API because bank spec is fixed. Webservice API is SOAP or Restful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation may be something like this:

- Always save transaction data to your database and mark it as "unprocessed".
- Use separate "worker" process, that fetches all unprocessed transaction from your database, and calls `pay` method of Bank payment system.
- Accordingly to `pay` method result, choose to change/not change the status of the transaction.

Worker may by a scheduled process (each XX sec/minutes/etc) or some service that queries unprocessed transactions constantly (maybe with some delay between loops).

So in case of "no result" from  Bank payment system, transaction state will not be changed and "pay" method will be retried on next worker run.